# The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a input Box using tkinter to create a UI interface which has a dialogue box to get the input filename path from the user and then load the data and process it ...

the problems are

1. when running the cell the filename is not getting loaded (i dont know what i did here is exactly how it should be done)
2. I am not able to close the tkinter UI once it gets generated
3. getting this message

> "The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell"

I had to reinstall the entire kernel and then all the training data got lost

please guide me though this

````
from keras.preprocessing import image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *   
from tkinter import filedialog

def openfile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return filename

parent = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(parent)
frame.pack()

text_disp= tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="open file ", 
                   command=openfile
                   )

text_disp.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

exit_button = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Exit",
                   fg="green",
                   command=quit)
exit_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

parent.mainloop()


# create a windown with title "select image for classification" and button to select the file
root = Tk()
root.title("select image for classification")
root.geometry("300x100")
button = Button(root, text="Select Image", command=openfile)
button.pack() 
root.mainloop()  


uploaded = filename

for fn in uploaded.keys():
    
    # predicting images
    path = fn
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x /= 255
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    images = np.vstack([x])
    classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
    print(classes[0])
    if classes[0]>0.5:
        print(fn + " is a human")
    else:
        print(fn + " is a horse")
    ```
````

Comment: There's a good chance it's just because your computer can't handle so much data processing. But can you update your tkinter and keras just in case?

Comment: i have tried it @wel still no use ... idts it processing so much data the model just classifies if its a human or horse and i just upload one image ..